# Difficulties in webscraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the prices from the following website using beautifulsoup in Python Jupyter. The element I want has a unique class of 'price average'. I tried using the findall function but am unable to scrape it. Can somebody help me see what is wrong?

Website: https://otc.hbg.com/en-us/trade/buy-usdt/

```
import requests
URL = 'https://otc.hbg.com/en-us/trade/buy-btc/' 
page = requests.get(URL)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "price average"})
containers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. But you can use `requests` module to parse necessary information:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://otc-api.hbg.com/v1/data/trade-market?coinId=1&currency=3&tradeType=sell&currPage=1&payMethod=0&country=153&blockType=general&online=1&range=0&amount='
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data['data']:
    print('{:<30}{}'.format(d['userName'], d['price']))
```

Prints:

```
CRXzone.com                   13286.95
CRXzone.com                   13352.66
cryptotil                     13352.66
coinhub                       13365.81
btcsg                         13470.94
108057692                     13470.94
yjyjyj                        13536.66
Silkroad1015                  13668.08
btcsg                         14193.78
digicryp                      16427.98
```

Comment: How do i make the URL dynamic becasue the URL changes everyday

Comment: do i need to use an api?

Comment: @HanishKiran The data is dynamically loaded, so you can use `selenium` and scrape the data with it. What are the other URLs?

Comment: Ok!! The numbers are refreshed regularly, I think the URL changes whenever the data is changed

Comment: @HanishKiran You can shorten the URL to `https://otc-api.hbg.com/v1/data/trade-market?coinId=1&currency=3&tradeType=sell&blockType=general` Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve cannot be done with the help of a webscraper since the element you're trying to scrape requires additional user interaction to even appear on the page. Look into web-automation with Selenium to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need selenium for this. Just query their [API](https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/):

```py
import requests

url = 'https://otc-api-hk.eiijo.cn/v1/data/trade-market?coinId=2&currency=4&tradeType=sell&currPage=1&payMethod=0&country=74&blockType=general&online=1&range=0&amount='

resp = requests.get(url).json()

for i in resp['data']:
    print(i['price'])
```

Comment: How do I make the URL dynamic because the URL is not static, it changes everyday